# What is the difference between '==' and '='?

Tags: java, operators

I know that one of them is bitwise and the other is logical but I can not figure this out:

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Enter ur integer");
int x=sc.nextInt();
if(x=0)//Error...it can not be converted from int to boolean
System.out.println("...");
```

The error means that `x` cannot be converted to `boolean` or the result of `x=0` can not be converted to `boolean`.

Comment: The bitwise and logical ones apply to AND(&) and OR(|) operators, not to the equal sign ones.

Comment: Also, please change your sysout. Two more keystrokes will save a puppy ("ur" kills puppies).

Comment: @Instantsoup: That explains lolcats.

Comment: why exactly was this question marked down? Was it because of the puppycide?

Comment: This is a valid question. Why is it marked down?

Comment: This is not a very good beginner question/example. The Scanner and System.out.println are irrelevant here.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

== checks for equality.
= is assignment.

What you're doing is:
`if( x = Blah )` - in Java this statement is illegal as you can not test the state of an assignment statement. Specifically, Java does not treat assignment as a boolean operation, which is required in an if statement. This is in contrast with C/C++, which DOES allow you to treat assignment as a boolean operation, and can be the result of many hair-pulling bugs.

Comment: The C++ compilers warn about this case. So if you're watching the warning errors, not only the compiler errors (recommended policy :) ), you'll notice it.

Comment: It's an equals expression (which may be an expression statement). The value of the expression, is the value of the right hand subexpression. if (x = y) is perfectly legal if x and y are of the boolean or Boolean.

Comment: C and C++ allow it (with warnings) because the test is whether the value is 0 or not (roughly). There is boolean type.

Comment: @Neda, since x and y are both booleans, if(x=y) equates to "Store the value of Y in X, and if the new value of X is 'true', do something.

Comment: *"Specifically, Java does not treat assignment as a boolean operation, which is required in an if statement."* -  Actually, that is incorrect.  The type of `x = Blah` will be `boolean` ... if and only if the type of `x` is `boolean`.

Answer (score 13):

When you write 'x = 0' you are saying "Store 0 in the variable x".  The return value on the whole expression is '0' (it's like this so you can say silly things like x = y = 0).

When you write 'x == 0' it says "Does x equal 0?".  The return value on this expression is going to be either 'true' or 'false'.

In Java, you can't just say if(0) because if expects a true/false answer.  So putting if(x = 0) is not correct, but if(x == 0) is fine.

Answer (score 5):

== is a comparison operator, and = is assignment.

Answer (score 4):

```
== is an equality check. if (x == 0) // if x equals 0
= is an assignment. x = 0; // the value of x is now 0
```

Answer (score 2):

I know the question has been answered, but this still comes up from time to time not as a programmer error but as a typographical error (i.e., the programmer knew what he meant, but failed).  It can be hard to see, since the two look so similar.

I've found that a way to help avoid doing this is to put the constant expression on the left-hand-side, like so:

```
if (0 == x) 
   ...
```

That way, if I accidentally use only one "=" sign, the compiler will fail with an error about assigning to a constant expression, whether or not the assignment operator is left-associative and whether the if conditional expects a strongly-typed Boolean.

Answer (score 1):

```
if(x=0)
```

Here you're *assigning* the value of 0 to the variable x.  The if statement in Java can't evaluate an integer argument as it can in many other languages.  In Java, if requires a boolean.  Try

```
if(x == 0)
```

to do a *comparison*.

Answer (score 1):

Interpret the error to mean

"The expression

```
x=0
```

cannot be converted to Boolean."

Answer (score 1):

Just to clarify about C/C++ - assignment is evaluated to the right operand

```
if(a = n)
```

is evaluated to n, so (n = 1) is true (n = 0) is false

Answer (score 1):

One interesting note: Since assignment operator evaluates to the right operand, the following is valid in Java(albeit not pretty):

```
if (( x = blah ) > 0) ...
```

Parenthesis are needed because of operator precedence ( '>' binds stronger than '=').

Answer (score 0):

As others have already said, '=' is assignment; '==' is compare.

in your program change

> if(x=0)

to

> if(x==0)

Answer (score 0):

```
"==" checks for equality



"=" Is used for assignment.
```

It is giving you error cause you're assigning value to x in if(), where you're supposed to check for the equality. Try changing it to equality instead of assignment operator.

Answer (score 0):

As others stated, `=` assigns while `==` compares.

However, these statements have their own values as well.

The `=` operator returns the value of its right-hand operand. This is how statements like `a = b = c = 5` work: they are parsed as `a = (b = (c = 5))`, which evaluates to `a = (b = 5)` and then `a = 5`.

The `==` operator returns a `boolean` that is `true` if its operands are equal. The `if` statement runs its body if its argument is `true`. Thus, `if` headers like `if (5 == 5)` translate to `if (true)`. This is why sometimes you see infinite `while` loops with header `while (true)`; the `while` loop runs "while" toe argument is true.

If you had a `boolean` in your `if` statement, it would give no error and run the code if the value being assigned (or "compared to") was `true`. This is why it is so important to *never* mix up the `=` and `==` operators, especially when working with `boolean`s.

Hope this helped!!